# glGetError() always returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION after successfully obtaining context

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I'm trying to get OpenGL ES 2.0 running using (Google's) Angle on Windows 7, however no matter where I put it, `glGetError()` infinitely returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I'm told it happens when there's no context, however I'm using EGL which produces no error.

I put `assert(eglGetError() == EGL_SUCCESS)` after every EGL statement just to check, and there were no errors.

However this hangs the program no matter where I put it, even straight after the `eglMakeCurrent()`:

```
while((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    ...    
}
```

Here is my EGL setup code (`window` is a `HWND`):

```
    mainDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if(mainDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        ...
    }
    if(eglInitialize(mainDisplay, NULL, NULL) != EGL_TRUE) {
        ...
    }
    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);
    EGLConfig bestConfiguration;
    EGLint numConfigurationsAvailable;
    if(!eglChooseConfig(mainDisplay, openGLConfigurationAttributes, &bestConfiguration, 1, &numConfigurationsAvailable)) {
        ...
    }
    const EGLint surfaceBaseAttributes[] = { EGL_NONE };
    displaySurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mainDisplay, bestConfiguration, window, surfaceBaseAttributes);
    if(displaySurface == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        ...
    }
    const EGLint contextBaseAttributes[] = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE };
    openGLContext = eglCreateContext(mainDisplay, bestConfiguration, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextBaseAttributes);
    if(openGLContext == EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
        ...
    }
    if(eglMakeCurrent(mainDisplay, displaySurface, displaySurface, openGLContext) != EGL_TRUE) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: So, take this with a grain of salt because I'm not really an expert on this cross-platform opengl stuff. But, my understanding was that ANGLE has been integrated into SDL2? And so it is enough for me to use SDL2 and request an opengles2 context from SDL2 and when it is on windows, ANGLE will implicitly be used? There are several posts on the SDL2 forums about this: https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=11315&sid=b2aab02965553c7d56c4914ee9d2f18d https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=10236&sid=8783661a52151c6a1f9e199369717343 This might not answer your question but it might help anyways

Comment: @Chris - In looking for an answer to my question, I have seen posts that mention that one version of SDL SOMETIMES uses Angle but not always. I don't wish to use it though, as I don't like extra dependencies and don't require the other facilities SDL offers. EGL is a perfect fit for me, assuming I can get it working. Worst case is I have to go back to WGL + XGL for cross-platform

Comment: You could try looking at the SDL code though, for how they engage Angle

Comment: What libraries you're linking with?

Comment: Just `libEGL` and `libGLESv2` from Angle (compiled from Google's Git). I tested them on the samples the sources came with

Comment: @Chris - Good idea. I did that for the Google code instead. They've set it up very differently than standard. See my answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

After all, I found out the problem was with a mismatch in resolution between the window and the input variables, which somehow EGL didn't pick up but GL knew there was an issue. I'd still like to know why it happened and how I can prevent such issues from happening.

To determine this, I had spent an inordinate amount of time analysing Google's sample code and found they initialise EGL extremely differently. In case it's helpful to someone, here's how Google initialise EGL in their `Angle` example:

```
PFNEGLGETPLATFORMDISPLAYEXTPROC eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT = reinterpret_cast(eglGetProcAddress("eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT"));
if(!eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT) {
    ...
}
const EGLint displayAttributes[] = {
    EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_TYPE_ANGLE, EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_TYPE_DEFAULT_ANGLE,
    EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_MAX_VERSION_MAJOR_ANGLE, EGL_DONT_CARE,
    EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_MAX_VERSION_MINOR_ANGLE, EGL_DONT_CARE,
    EGL_NONE
};
mainWindowDisplay = eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT(EGL_PLATFORM_ANGLE_ANGLE, display, &displayAttributes[0]);
if(mainWindowDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
    ...
}

EGLint majorVersion, minorVersion;
if(eglInitialize(mainWindowDisplay, &majorVersion, &minorVersion) == EGL_FALSE) {
    ...
}

const char *displayExtensions = eglQueryString(mainWindowDisplay, EGL_EXTENSIONS);
bool hasKHRCreateContext = strstr(displayExtensions, "EGL_KHR_create_context") != nullptr;
if((majorVersion != 2 || minorVersion != 0) && !hasKHRCreateContext) {
    ...
}

eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);
if(eglGetError() != EGL_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}

const EGLint configAttributes[] = {
    EGL_RED_SIZE,       8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE,     8,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE,      8,
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,     8,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,     24,
    EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,   8,
    EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 0,
    EGL_NONE
};
EGLConfig graphicsConfig;
EGLint configCount;
if(!eglChooseConfig(mainWindowDisplay, configAttributes, &graphicsConfig, 1, &configCount) || (configCount != 1)) {
    ...
}

EGLint surfaceAttributes[] = {
    EGL_POST_SUB_BUFFER_SUPPORTED_NV, EGL_TRUE,
    EGL_NONE
};
if(strstr(displayExtensions, "EGL_NV_post_sub_buffer") == nullptr) {
    surfaceAttributes[0] = EGL_NONE;
}
mainWindowSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mainWindowDisplay, graphicsConfig, window, &surfaceAttributes[0]);
if(eglGetError() != EGL_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}
assert(mainWindowSurface != EGL_NO_SURFACE);

EGLint contextAttributes[] = {
    EGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_KHR, 2,
    EGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_KHR, 0,
    EGL_NONE
};
if(!hasKHRCreateContext) {
    contextAttributes[0] = EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION;
    contextAttributes[2] = EGL_NONE;
}
mainWindowContext = eglCreateContext(mainWindowDisplay, graphicsConfig, nullptr, &contextAttributes[0]);
if(eglGetError() != EGL_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}

eglMakeCurrent(mainWindowDisplay, mainWindowSurface, mainWindowSurface, mainWindowContext);
if(eglGetError() != EGL_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}
```